# bash shell addition and subtraction

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file.

Info in text file is

```
Book1:Author1:10.50:50:5
Book2:Author2:4.50:30:10
```

First one is book name, second is author name, third is the price, fourth is the quantity and fifth is the quantity sold.

I am trying to update the noCpySold. So when I do this, the quantity avaliable (4th column) will go down and the quantity sold (5th column) will go up.

```
read -p $'No of copies sold: ' noCpySold

sed -re "s/${Title}:${Author}:([^:]+):([^:]+)([^:]+)/${Title}:${Author}:\1:\1-${noCpySold}:\1+$noCpySold/g" BookDB.txt > tempBook.txt
mv -f tempBook.txt BookDB.txt
```

I tested this code but the subtraction and addition wasnt updated.. anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN {OFS=":"} { $4--; $5++; print $0}' filename >newfile
 mv newfile filename
```

This is an awk example.
Edit:

```
 num_sold=13
    awk -F: -v sold=$num_sold 'BEGIN {OFS=":"} { $4-=sold; $5+=sold; print $0}' filename >newfile
     mv newfile filename
```

Comment: does this mean i can do $4-$noCpySold; $5+$noCpySold ?

Comment: Not like that -- see the edit to the answer above.  Note -v  also note the -= and +- operators.